# Can Resteasy look into parameter's type for JAX-RS methods?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, resteasy

We were using Resteasy 3.0.9 for our JAX-RS webservices, and recently switched to 3.0.19, where we started to see a lot of `RESTEASY002142: Multiple resource methods match request` warnings.

For example, we have methods like:

```
@Path("/{id}") 
public String getSome(UUID id)

@Path("/{id}") 
public String getSome(int id)
```

I'm not sure how it worked in 3.0.9, probably, we just were very lucky as Resteasy seems to select first method from all candidates (and 3.0.19 sorts candidate methods).

One solution is to explicitly specify regex: `@Path("/{id : [0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}}")`

But is there a way to somehow tell Resteasy to look into method parameters and construct appropriate regex automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, RESTEasy won't take the method parameter type into consideration when matching a request. According the [JSR-339](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) (that RESTEasy implements), this is how the request matching process works:

> A request is matched to the corresponding resource method or sub-resource method by comparing the normalized
>   request URI, the media type of any request entity, and the requested response
>   entity format to the metadata annotations on the resource classes and their methods. If no matching resource
>   method or sub-resource method can be found then an appropriate error response is returned. [...]

The JAX-RS implementations must match the requested URI with the [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation values. In the [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation value you can define variables, that are denoted by braces (`{` and `}`).

As part of the request matching, the JAX-RS implementation will replace each URI template variable with the *specified regular expression* or `([ˆ/]+?)` if no regular expression is specified.

To address the situation you mentioned in your question, you should specify a regex to match UUIDs on one resource method:

```java
@Path("{id : [0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}}")
```

And you also may consider a regex to match integers on the other resource method:

```java
@Path("{id : \\d+}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However, that does not answer the question fully. JAX-RS 2.0 specification does not forbid implementations to look into parameter types during step 2 of the request matching:

For each class Z in C add regular expressions to E for each sub-resource method and locator as follows:
i. For each sub-resource method D, add R(TD) where TD is the URI path template of the sub-resource method.

Resteasy already converts templates like ```/things/{id}``` into regular expressions. So there is a possibility for type-based regexes.

Comment: So, the part "At least, it shouldn't" is not correct, according to JAX-RS 2.0 specification. If I'm wrong, please point me to the exact place where the specification forbids it.

Comment: @relgames The JAX-RS 2.0 specification states that implementations are not required to use the algorithm as written in the specification but must produce results equivalent to those produced by the algorithm described in the specification. The JAX-RS 2.0 specification does not forbid implementations to look into method types parameter and, as far as I know, RESTEasy doesn't do it.

Comment: @relgames Regarding the regular expressions when matching requests, have a look at the section _3.7.3_ (_Converting URI Templates to Regular Expressions_) of the JAX-RS 2.0 specification. For this situation, the step 3 is the most relevant: _Replace each URI template variable with a capturing group containing the specified regular expression or `([ˆ/]+?)` if no regular expression is specified._ So, for the template variable, the JAX-RS implementation will use _your regular expression_ or _the default one_.

Comment: Fair enough. Accepting the answer.