# RESTEASY002142: Multiple resource methods match request

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am getting following for two completely different URLs and I cannot explain why:

```
RESTEASY002142: 

   Multiple resource methods match request "GET /devices/distinctValues/3". 
   Selecting one. 

Matching methods: 
[public javax.ws.rs.core.Response 
mypackage.DevService.getDistinctValues(int) throws java.lang.Exception, 

public javax.ws.rs.core.Response 
mypackage.DevRESTService.getDevice(int,java.lang.String) 
throws java.lang.Exception]
```

This warning should not come up, since the URLS are completely different. If anybody knows why this is happening:

URLs for both methods:

`getDevice`:

```
@GET
@Path("devices/{customerId}/{deviceIds}")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
```

`getDistinctValues`:

```
@GET
@Path("devices/distinctValues/{customerId}")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning happens because your request string can match both path templates. The request `"devices/distinctValues/3"`

- matches `devices/distinctValues/{customerId}` in that `customerId = "3"`
- matches `devices/{customerId}/{deviceIds}` in that `customerId = "distinctValues"` and `deviceIds = "3"`.

[There is no type resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635174/can-resteasy-look-into-parameters-type-for-jax-rs-methods) and since your request is a `String` there is no way to tell `customerId` that it cannot accept `"distinctValues"`.

As a workaround, you can either specify a regex as shown in the linked question, or use the [RESTEasy proxy framework](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2024) which is basically a shared interface that both server (your JAX-RS resource) and client use, and then you have a common language with type resolution. Note that there is a typo in the example of the docs.